# IS NOT DISTINCT FROM vs row-wise equality with =

Tags: postgresql, null, condition, row

Looking at the below query,

```
SELECT null IS NOT DISTINCT FROM null AS indf,
  null = null AS eq;
 indf | eq 
------+----
 t    |
```

From this we can see the result of the `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` is `true`, and the result of the `eq` is `false`. The following then logically follows from that,

```
-- returns 1 row.
SELECT *
FROM ( VALUES (null) ) AS t(a)
JOIN ( VALUES (null) ) AS g(a)
  ON t.a IS NOT DISTINCT FROM g.a;

-- returns 0 rows.
SELECT *
FROM ( VALUES (null) ) AS t(a)
JOIN ( VALUES (null) ) AS g(a)
  ON t.a = g.a;
```

Because if the condition returns `null` the `join` fails. But, this throws me off, with [*row-wise comparison*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparisons.html#ROW-WISE-COMPARISON)

```
-- returns 1 row.
SELECT *
FROM ( VALUES (null) ) AS t(a)
JOIN ( VALUES (null) ) AS g(a)
  ON (t) IS NOT DISTINCT FROM (g);

-- also returns one row.
SELECT * 
FROM ( VALUES (null) ) AS t(a)
JOIN ( VALUES (null) ) AS g(a)
  ON (t) = (g);
```

Why does [*row-wise comparison*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparisons.html#ROW-WISE-COMPARISON) treat `null`s different than scalar comparison? And is there a point of `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` in row-wise comparison?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This behavior is documented under Composite Type Comparison,](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparisons.html#COMPOSITE-TYPE-COMPARISON)

> The SQL specification requires row-wise comparison to return NULL if the result depends on comparing two `NULL` values or a `NULL` and a non-`NULL`. **PostgreSQL does this only when comparing the results of two row constructors** (as in Section 9.23.5) or comparing a row constructor to the output of a subquery (as in Section 9.22). In other contexts where two composite-type values are compared, two `NULL` field values are considered equal, and a `NULL` is considered larger than a non-`NULL`. **This is necessary in order to have consistent sorting and indexing behavior for composite types.**

This essentially means that the standard behavior can only be seen in the following syntax (`ROW()` is the row-constructor):

```
SELECT * FROM ( VALUES (null) ) AS t(a)
JOIN ( VALUES (null) ) AS g(a)
  ON ROW(t.*) = ROW(g.*);
```

versus,

```
SELECT * FROM ( VALUES (null) ) AS t(a)
JOIN ( VALUES (null) ) AS g(a)
  ON ROW(t.*) IS NOT DISTINCT FROM ROW(g.*);
```

Just using the ROW constructor with the type will not work either `ON ROW(t) = ROW(g)`